# :valid ~ label is not working, input html element is not valid but registers as it is

Tags: html, css

I was making a new login using html and css and i want to make an affect with the label i placed on top of the input. the label will go to the top a little and change in font size when the input is :focus and :valid, but when i add all the css properties i want for the :valid part, it registers as if the input is valid when there is literally no text in there what so ever. im using chrome btw.

ive already tried positioning as well as looking online for some answers but cant find any.

here is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <p>login</p>
            <form>
                <div class="txtb">
                    <input type="text">
                    <label>username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="txtb">
                    <input type="password">
                    <label>password</label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my css:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container .txtb label,
.container p {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: white;
}

.container,
.main-container {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .4s;
}

.container:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);   
}

.main-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image: url('/images/bg-img.png');
    background-position: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}

.container p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.container .txtb {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 40px 0 40px;
}

.container .txtb input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 195px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    outline: 0;
}

.container .txtb label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 1px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .3s;
}

.container .txtb input:focus ~ label,
.container .txtb input:valid ~ label {
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

im expecting some good answers and or solutions to this problem. if there are no solutions, im happy with just some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your inputs has a `required` or `pattern` attribute or any other feature that would impose a validity condition.

They are both *always* valid, so the `:valid` pseudo-class applies.

MDN has [an introduction to form validity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Using_built-in_form_validation) that will help you use those attributes to apply whatever validity rules you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the required attribute worked. could you tell me why that needs to be there for it to work?

Comment: @Lolzzz1093 — I already did. If you don't say that it is *required* to put something in the element for it to be valid, then it is valid even if you don't put something in it.

Comment: so in other words, `required` is saying that its not valid until something is typed in the `input` element?

Comment: @Lolzzz1093 also use the adjacent sibling combinator: `+` instead of the general combinator: `~` so each label style will only apply to the previous input only.